# Pandas dataframe manipulation

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying perform a specific operation on a dataframe.
Given the following dataframe:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
'id': [0, 1, 2, 1, 3, 0],
'letter': ['a','b','c','b','b','a'],
'status':[0,1,0,0,0,1]})

id letter  status
0   a     0
1   b     1
2   c     0
1   b     0
3   b     0
0   a     1
```

I'd like to create another dataframe which contains rows from df1 based on the following restriction.
If 2 or more rows have the same id and letter, then return whichever row has a status of 1. All other rows must be copied over.
The resulting dataframe should look like this:

```
id letter  status
 0      a       1
 1      b       1
 2      c       0
 3      b       0
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Check out the groupby().filter method that should probably do what you like.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

this should work:

```
>>> fn = lambda obj: obj[obj.status == 1] if any(obj.status == 1) else obj
>>> df.groupby(['id', 'letter'], as_index=False).apply(fn)
   id letter  status
5   0      a       1
1   1      b       1
2   2      c       0
4   3      b       0

[4 rows x 3 columns]
```

Comment: This solution works great! However it doesn't scale well. My data set contains approximately 3 million rows and the code has been running for about an hour with no result yet. Any idea how to improve the run-time?

Answer (score 1):

sort by `status` first and then use `groupby`

```
In [1932]: df.sort_values(by='status').groupby('id', as_index=False).last()
Out[1932]:
   id letter  status
0   0      a       1
1   1      b       1
2   2      c       0
3   3      b       0
```